# I am filtering the data in prisma and I want to sort the data response in the same schema function

Tags: mysql, sorting, nestjs, schema, prisma

I want to sort the response in the same prisma function where I am filtering the data in prisma. I am using related data and got many relations and its hard to sort that data. Here is my code in which I am specifying the response and want to sort the data through the fee of hospitals.
here is my code:

```
const filteredDoctorsBySpecialty: PaginatorTypes.PaginatedResult<DoctorSpecialty> =
    await paginate(
      this.prisma.doctorSpecialty,
      {
        where,
        select: {
          doctor: {
            include: {
              _count: {
                select: {
                  reviews: true,
                },
              },
              hospitals: {
                where: {
                  hospital: {
                    city_id: cityId,
                    area_id: areaId,
                  },
                },
                select: {
                  hospital: true,
                  fee: true,
                  time_slots: startTime || endTime ? {
                    where: {
                      OR: [
                        {
                          AND: [
                            {
                              start_time: {
                                lte: startTime, // Check if the database start time is before or at the same time as the provided start time
                              },
                            },
                            {
                              end_time: {
                                gte: startTime, // Check if the database end time is after or at the same time as the provided start time
                              },
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                        {
                          AND: [
                            {
                              start_time: {
                                lte: endTime, // Check if the database start time is before or at the same time as the provided end time
                              },
                            },
                            {
                              end_time: {
                                gte: endTime, // Check if the database end time is after or at the same time as the provided end time
                              },
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  } : true, // Include time_slots if startTime or endTime is provided, otherwise, set it to true
                },
              },
            }, 
          },
        },
      },
      pagination,
    );
  
  return filteredDoctorsBySpecialty;
  }
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).